# Link Android Room Database with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection, android-room

I am using **Android Room Database** for creating the database for my android app. It works perfectly for me locally but I cannot link to a server to have it online as well.
I am using Firebase for Authentication. I am trying to use **Firebase Realtime Database** to save the whole database object from Room and load the correct database on app startup according to the authenticated user.

I want to ask if this is possible at all? and if I can just save a whole instance of Room database or I need to re-create the database on Firebase and save my data item by item?

I also can't seem to be able to get access to the database data of Room, as when I get an object of the AppDatabase class it doesn't really pass the data. And I don't know how should do the opposite, to assign the data retrieved from Firebase later to the local data saved?

Also if it's not possible with Firebase, do you have any recommendation for some other server I can use with Room?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a lot of researches and looking desperately for an answer here's what I reached:

- Firebase already got a straight forward way to create the database and host it online. *(I had my database already created so was trying to save time, but creating it from scratch using Firebase Realtime Database was a lot faster)*
- Room Database is quite perfect if you are planning to save your database **locally and offline** *(Up to the post date)*

Comment: Remember, Firebase Realtime database also offers persistence (offline) storage which works seamlessly like Room database. Add below line in your Application class [Manifest file -> Application -> android:name] to initiate this process at once.  `/* Enable disk persistence  */
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Comment: @PravyNandas Yea I found out that this was an option too, it was quite useful for me since I needed online and offline working together! However, Room was more easier for me to use when I needed only an offline database! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I've got a similar task. I'm going to use Room as local storage, but I need a sync/backup functional too. For this purpose, I'm going to use replication log in Firebase. It's a single collection with "flat" representation of a Room's data.

Comment: That would be a good option definitely if you just need a flat representation. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

I think their is no need to connect your Room Database with Firebase Realtime database because,okay first try to solve this problem, why we use Room Database ?because when we don't have internet, we can get data from Room Database , no need of network... Firebase also provides offline mode , it can also save data in persistence, so why we use Room Database ?.. Hope you got the point...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read through the question and accepted answer for better details.